# Crawling Highcharts via python selenium ( javascript error: Highcharts is not defined )

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to crawl graphs from a website. It is a graph that shows the search trend of a certain keyword. But the thing is that the graph is interactive. It would only pop up when I click the keyword in the list. (When it pops up, it is not a new window).

Via the developer tools element tab, I found that this is sth called highcharts. 
Is there any way that I can crawl the chart data via selenium?

Using beautifulsoup and getting json would not work because there is no url assigned to the chart.. (as I mentioned earlier, it is just a pop-up)

I would attach the image of the website and the element tab.

[Image #1 of the chart and element tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXes.png)

[Image #2 of the chart and element tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q6nS.png)

Thankyou!!

(It is a Korean website and one needs to register for it, so I would not post the website url)

### CODE UPDATE

```py
keyword = '괌여행'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/elena-root/elena-wrap/div/div[2]/elena-tool-wrap/div/div/div/div/elena-keyword-planner/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/textarea'))).send_keys(keyword)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/elena-root/elena-wrap/div/div[2]/elena-tool-wrap/div/div/div/div/elena-keyword-planner/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button').click()

time.sleep(1)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/elena-root/elena-wrap/div/div[2]/elena-tool-wrap/div/div/div/div/elena-keyword-planner/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/elena-table/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/elena-keyword').click()

time.sleep(1)

actions = wd.ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/elena-root/elena-wrap/div/div[2]/elena-tool-wrap/div/div/div/div/elena-keyword-planner/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/elena-table/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/elena-keyword'))

actions.click()
actions.perform()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to_active_element()
time.sleep(1)

#The following code using Highcharts.charts gives an error "JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Highcharts is not defined"

d = driver.execute_script('return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data')
data = [item[1] for item in data]
print(data)
```

Comment: you can do click on a keyboard and popup graphs as you said and then you can screenshot of that chart. or any other option like right-click and check save as options or other options can work.

Comment: Hi @Summer Cho, You should be able to get data by global variable `Highcharts`. Please check `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data`.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek for the comment!! 
I have already tried that but the error shows
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Highcharts is not defined. 

--> I'll update my code on the post!

Comment: Thank you @ManaliKagathara Screenshot would work but I would like to save the data not as a jpg , but crawl the numerical data of x and y :) ! Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe the data is dynamically downloaded and you can somehow intercepting it?